# Apex method not creating record

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, debugging, insert, create-records

My apex class is as follows:

```
global class CreateDailyRSLI implements Schedulable{

    List<Wildlife__c> LiveRhinosList = [SELECT id, Number_of_Sightings_Today__c 
    FROM Wildlife__c];

    Rhino_Sighting_Line_Item__c RSLIrecord = new Rhino_Sighting_Line_Item__c();
    Date d = Date.today();

    global void execute (SchedulableContext SC) {
        for(Integer a = 0; a < LiveRhinosList.size(); a++){
            RSLIrecord.Date_of_sighting_line_item__c = d;
            RSLIrecord.Active_Wildlife__c = LiveRhinosList[a].Id;
            RSLIrecord.Number_consecutive_days_missing__c = 
                LiveRhinosList[a].Days_since_last_sighting__c;
            insert RSLIrecord;
            System.debug('Step 2 - '+ a + ' ' + LiveRhinosList[a].Name__c);
        } 
    }
}
```

I scheduled this Apex For some reason this class is not inserting any values. 
The Debug logs are as shown below:

```
 (766396)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
 (817903)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
 (840252)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
 (864071)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
 (884440)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
 (923630)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
 (945131)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:1
 (951324)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:2
 (961088)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p6C0000008c8f|CreateDailyRSLI.CreateDailyRSLI()
 (964411)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
 (968662)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
 (973518)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|CreateDailyRSLI
 (1308373)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:16
 (1478972)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1]|this|CreateDailyRSLI|true|false
 (1538974)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1]|this|{}|0x6ee55e5b
 (1550890)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:6
 (1592063)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
 (1593650)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
 (1596894)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:56
 (1606948)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:4
 (1627890)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
 (1641209)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
 (1646883)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
 (3769547)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[3]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id, Number_of_Sightings_Today__c FROM Wildlife__c
 (15977962)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[3]|Rows:7
 (15998530)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:32
 (16021324)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:203
 (16057818)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[3]|Bytes:32
 (16106052)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[3]|this.LiveRhinosList|{"s":1,"v":"List of size 7 too large to display"}|0x6ee55e5b
 (16110480)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[5]
 (16126431)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[5]|Bytes:4
 (16239405)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[5]|this.RSLIrecord|{}|0x6ee55e5b
 (16242095)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[6]
 (16309149)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[6]|Bytes:4
 (16340409)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[6]|this.d|"2016-10-25T00:00:00.000Z"|0x6ee55e5b
 (51585737)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CreateDailyRSLI
 (52590204)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

What could be the problem? Completely clueless why this didn't execute.

Comment: you need to bulkify your code, DML is inside a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you called your code like this:

```
System.scheduleJob(jobName, cronString, new CreateDailyRSLI());
```

There will be a separate log that will be created when the scheduled job kicks off. Your execute method won't appear in the same log that created the scheduled task. You'll probably want to set up a debug log in Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs and wait for the class to execute.

Note that your scheduled job is crashing because you're only creating one "new" record for all 7 records you're trying to insert, which is causing it to crash because the Id field isn't being reset. The correct way to create records is to create a list, and insert them all at once.

```
Rhino_Sighting_Line_Item__c[] records = new Rhino_Sighting_Line_Item__c[0];
for(Integer a = 0; a < LiveRhinosList.size(); a++){
    Rhino_Sighting_Line_Item__c RSLIrecord = new Rhino_Sighting_Line_Item__c();
    RSLIrecord.Date_of_sighting_line_item__c = d;
    RSLIrecord.Active_Wildlife__c = LiveRhinosList[a].Id;
    RSLIrecord.Number_consecutive_days_missing__c = LiveRhinosList[a].Days_since_last_sighting__c;
    records.add(RSLIrecord);
}
insert records;
```

Comment: Waiting to test it again in the next hour according to the scheduled times available,

Comment: You can test your code manually at any time, just do the following: `new CreateDailyRSLI().execute(null);` in the Developer Console in the Execute Anonymous window. It'll even give you debug logs which should help you figure out why it's not working.